# PHP MailParse to Read and Process Incoming Emails

Tags: php

I am currently able to read incoming emails by using the PHP [MailParse Extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/mailparse), what I am having problems with is the formatting of the emails. The body of the email message is wrapped 76 characters and adds extra spacing.

I like to know if there is setting with PHP to eliminate this or do I have to write separate script to clean this up?

Comment: The line wrapping usually occurs at the client.

Answer (score 0):

All email clients wrap body lines at a maximum of 80 lines as it it required in the specs. There is nothing you can do against it except try to detect if the part of the text is a paragraph and join the lines again. Most mail clients do this and fail sometimes.